# AngularJs BootStrap UI Pagination

Tags: angularjs, pagination, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am attempting to use bootstrap ui's pagination on and angularjs project. I am receiving error message 'Error: [$injector:modulerr]'. I have been following the example here [Angular UI bootstrap pagination not working inside ui.bootstrap.tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31148039/angular-ui-bootstrap-pagination-not-working-inside-ui-bootstrap-tabs) however i'm using json to retrieve data so my code is slightly different.

I've created a Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/omQ2qxgkmK5HAkd0wBC6 to display my code.

These are the CDNs I am using for the project:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular-route.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.1.1/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Have you injected ui.bootstrap into your angular app module? i.e. var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap'])

Comment: yes, I injected ui.bootstrap var defaultPage = angular.module('DefaultPage', ['ui.bootstrap']);

Comment: The apps.js file, containing the definition of the main GithubIssues module, is not included in the html page. Read the error message. It says: *Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module GithubIssues due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'GithubIssues' is not available!*.

Comment: @JBNizet when I inject  'ui-bootstrap' in  apps.angular.module('GithubIssues', ['ui-bootstrap']) the problem still exists.

Comment: Read my comment again. Read the error message again. I never told you to do that. I told you to ass the apps.js script in the html page.

Comment: the error message is foreign to me. I don't understand what it's asking me to do.

Comment: Read my comment again. The message complains that the module GithubIssues is not defined. Is it defined somewhere in the code? Yes, in apps.js. But, is the apps.js file loaded by the HTML page? NO, IT IS NOT. Because there is no `<script src="apps.js"></script>` in the HTML page.

Comment: Thanks for explain @JBNizet Nizet. Yes, A reference to <script src="js/apps.js"></script>  and ng-app="GithubIssues" are define in index.html .

Comment: Because you just added them 2 minutes ago. Now read the new error message. It now compains about ui.bootstrap not being available. Is there a script in the html file that loads angular-ui-bootstrap? No, there is not. Same message, same mistake.

Comment: @JBNizet No, I added apps.js to the Plunker 2mins ago, however the application on my desktop had the script in index.html. :) This is the error I am receiving in Chrome developer Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=GithubIssues&p1=Err…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.9%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A463)

Comment: All we have is your plunkr. You didn't post any code, and any error message. How are we supposed to guess what the problem is without this critical information. Stop using the minified version of angular: you'll have clear error messages. And post the code and the error in the question. Delete thelink to the plunkr if it sn't the same code as the one you're actually using.

Comment: @JBNizet I've updated my Plunker with my most recent code.

Comment: And you still don't read my comments, and the error messages in the console: you're trying to load filters.js, which doesn't exist. Your app.js depends on angular-ui-bootstrap, but there is no script loading angular-ui-bootstrap in the HTML page. It's the third time you make the same mistake.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you for your help.